# GitHub Pages: Creating and deploying the report

Tags: postman, github-actions, newman

During the pipeline run, I'm creating a `docs` folder which should contain the generated `index.html` and then I want to use it as a source for GitHub Pages.

At the moment, the `docs` folder is not created at all (maybe because that this folder is empty and auto deletes). My question is what's wrong inside my code? I have tried everything I could, locally this command:

```bash
newman run petstore.collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export docs/index.html
```

works fine, but on CI, it doesn't.

```yaml
name: Test-Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test-api:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # INstall Node on the runner
      - name: Install Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "16.x"
      - run: npm i npm@latest
      - run: npm i

      # Install the newman command line utility and also install the html extra reporter
      - name: Install newman
        run: |
          npm install -g newman
          npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra

      # Make directory to upload the test results
      - name: Make Directory for results
        run: mkdir -p docs

      # Run the POSTMAN collection
      - name: Run POSTMAN collection
        run: |
          newman run petstore.collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export docs/index.html || true

      # Upload the contents of docs directory to workspace
      - name: Output the run Details
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: RunReports
          path: docs
```

Comment: Please include the workflow run logs in your question as well. With `|| true`, the failures won't make your CI fail. Was that intentional? You can add `ls -l docs` after `newman` command to verify its contents.

Comment: @Azeem Seems like the problem was that this index.html was not saving at all with my current code and that's why everything seemed right but was not as I expected. I have reworked my code and now it does what I wanted. I will attach the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed with code rework:

```
name: Test-Build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  test-api:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "16.x"
      - run: npm i npm@latest
      - run: npm i
      - name: Install newman
        run: |
          npm install -g newman
          npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
      
      - name: Run POSTMAN collection
        run: |
          newman run petstore.collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export docs/index.html || true

      - name: Add, commit and push changes
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add docs/index.html
          git commit -m "Add generated index.html" -a
          git push https://${{secrets.TEST_SECRET}}@github.com/${{github.repository}}.git HEAD:main
    
      - name: Output the run Details
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: RunReports
          path: docs
```

Comment: you should also write about the why of the code-rework, not only show the reworked code. this will make it easier to follow and better document your solution.